# What is trivial step size vs non-trivial step size?

Tags: gradient-descent

In the TRPO paper, the authors say

> we first prove that minimizing a certain surrogate objective function guarantees policy improvement with non-trivial step sizes.

What is a non-trivial step size? 1e-2 , 1e-3?

TRPO paper : [arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf)

Comment: Where does it say that? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf

Comment: Page1. DO a ctrl+F. It's the opening line of the last paragraph in the introduction.

Comment: What is the TRPO paper?

Comment: JMP has given a link - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf